# Do something if Array element starts with a certain letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

(Or does not start with certain letter)
Consider the array:

```
myArray = ['M1','M2','A1']
```

And:

```
if ( myArray[1] !== *START WITH M* ) { // something };
```

Is there a selector which I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( myArray[1].indexOf('M') != 0)
```

Code within the if block will execute if the string does not start with 'M'

Answer (score 1):

You can get at the first character of a string using the `charAt(x)` function like this:

```
if (myArray[1].charAt(0) !== 'M') { /* do something */ }
```

Also, FWIW, the `indexOf` approach mentioned below also works but its much slower the `charAt` in this particular chase. No reason to iterate over the entire string and find the location of the character in question when all you want is the first. Speed test here --> http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-charat

Comment: No prob, glad I could help.